# Enterprise Library 4: logging block flat file

Tags: enterprise-library, enterprise

I am having problem creating log entry to a text file. Here is my logging configuration in my ASP.net app.

and here is my vb.net code

Try
                        db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, tr)
                        tr.Commit()
                        result = True
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Dim entry As New LogEntry()
                        entry.EventId = 11
                        entry.Message = ex.Message
                        entry.Categories.Add("General")
                        Logger.Write(entry)

```
                    tr.Rollback()
                End Try
```

All the tutorial and example that i found so far are based on older version of Enterprise Library. I'm using Enterprise Library 4. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Is it my code or the configuration? Where can i find more tutorial on Enterprise Library version 4. I tried to follow the quick start that it come with but i can't make head or tail.

Answer (score 1):

its a basic tutorial on using enterprise library 4.1

http://blog.accentient.com/EnterpriseLibraryLogging101.aspx

btw, to get mine to work, i had to change all the PublicKeyToken's to = null
otherwise the web.config didnt validate, gl